# Can Apache serve proxy requests for websites on non-standard ports?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, http, port

I have a web server running at `192.168.1.100` and an Apache 2.2 proxy running at `192.168.1.1`

If my web server is listening in on the standard port 80 then I can successfully make an HTTP request

```
GET http://192.168.1.100/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.100
```

and get back a response.  However, if my web server is running on a non-standard port like 12345 then my request to the proxy

```
GET http://192.168.1.100:12345/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.100:12345
```

fails by returning a 404.  I can access this page directly when the web server is running on either port 80 or 12345, I can access it through the proxy when the web server is running on port 80, but I can't access it through the proxy when the web server is running on port 12345.

Is there some kind of Apache configuration I need to set to allow requests to go to web servers on nonstandard ports?

EDIT:  I should specify that I need a generic forward proxy that can access any site on the internet in addition to these local sites which run on nonstandard ports, so I can't simply set up a reverse proxy without adding configuration for every internal website.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse Proxy

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://server.com:12345/
ProxyPassReverse / http://server.com:12345/
```

-- may work without the / in front but this is how is written into the docs.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to access lots of websites rather than just this one, so I need a forward rather than reverse proxy.

Comment: not sure I get it - how do you set the forward - from what is written so far you have a proxy - not a reversed proxy and you want the ability to proxy on non standard ports ...

Comment: I have a standard proxy setup via `ProxyRequests On` and it's important that I be able to get at `192.168.1.100:12345` via a normal proxy request like `GET http://192.168.1.100:12345/ HTTP/1.1` which is why using `ProxyPass` and/or `ProxyPassReverse` is infeasible.  Regardless, thanks for your help so far.